# Appium not getting the list of all the elements for xpath windows application

Tags: appium, appium-desktop

There are around 120+ items in a list but appium is getting only 60 or 61 or 62 (max 63). How to get the list of all 120+ items
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Only those elements will be returned that are currently in the focus of the screen at that time. You have to scroll down to get the remaining.